# Rbenv not rehashing correctly and making shims

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, rbenv

The bottom line is, rbenv isn't making shims. I've exhausted ideas of what could be the problem. After a few days of banging my head against a wall to fix but no avail, I think it's time to ask for help.

I'm attempting to make the switch from RVM to rbenv, so that could obviously be a factor here. Any ideas/help would be great.

Here's what happens:

```
[09:38] ~ $ gem install pry
Fetching: pry-0.10.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed pry-0.10.2
1 gem installed

[09:39] ~ $ rbenv rehash

[09:40] ~ $ pry
bash: pry: command not found

[09:40] ~ $ rbenv which pry
rbenv: pry: command not found

[09:40] ~ $ which pry
which: no pry in (/home/caveman/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:/home/caveman/.rbenv/shims:/home/caveman/.rbenv/bin:/home/caveman/.rbenv/shims:/home/caveman/.rbenv/bin:/home/caveman/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:/home/caveman/.rbenv/shims:/home/caveman/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl)

[09:41] ~ $ ~/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/bin/pry 
[1] pry(main)> puts "I'm working now"
I'm working now

[09:43] ~ $ gem list | grep pry
pry (0.10.2)
```

Here's my gem environment:

```
[09:44] ~ $ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.8
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.2.0 (2014-12-25 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/caveman/.gem/ruby/2.2.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/caveman/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/caveman/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/caveman/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY:  /home/caveman/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/caveman/.gem/ruby/2.2.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "--no-document"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /home/caveman/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/bin
     - /usr/lib/rbenv/libexec
     - /home/caveman/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin
     - /home/caveman/.rbenv/shims
     - /home/caveman/.rbenv/bin
     - /home/caveman/.rbenv/shims
     - /home/caveman/.rbenv/bin
     - /home/caveman/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin
     - /home/caveman/.rbenv/shims
     - /home/caveman/.rbenv/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /usr/lib/jvm/default/bin
     - /usr/bin/site_perl
     - /usr/bin/vendor_perl
     - /usr/bin/core_perl
```

Here is my .bashrc file:

```
[09:46] ~ $ cat .bashrc
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[[ $- != *i* ]] && return

# If I don't set this, gem reverts back to nonexistent RVM directory.
export GEM_HOME=$(ruby -e 'print Gem.user_dir')
export GEM_PATH=$(ruby -e 'print Gem.user_dir')

export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"
```

And here is .bash_profile:

```
[09:52] ~ $ cat .bash_profile 

[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc

source ~/.profile

export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect your .bashrc is the problem. It shouldn't contain:

```
# If I don't set this, gem reverts back to nonexistent RVM directory.
export GEM_HOME=$(ruby -e 'print Gem.user_dir')
export GEM_PATH=$(ruby -e 'print Gem.user_dir')

export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"
```

Of my ~/.bashrc, ~/.profile and ~/.bash_profile files, only the last has configuration for rbenv:

```
# echo Using rbenv...
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

That was created when I installed rbenv, which matches the settings for my other systems where I use rbenv, including some that previously had RVM installed.

Your double PATH assignments look like the culprit. Compare the PATH for my system to yours, which is listed by `gem env`:

```
 - /Users/ttm/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin
 - /Users/ttm/.rbenv/libexec
 - /Users/ttm/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin
 - /Users/ttm/.rbenv/plugins/rbenv-whatis/bin
 - /Users/ttm/.rbenv/plugins/rbenv-vars/bin
 - /Users/ttm/.rbenv/plugins/rbenv-use/bin
 - /Users/ttm/.rbenv/plugins/rbenv-update/bin
 - /Users/ttm/.rbenv/plugins/rbenv-update-rubies/bin
 - /Users/ttm/.rbenv/plugins/rbenv-gemset/bin
 - /Users/ttm/.rbenv/plugins/rbenv-env/bin
 - /Users/ttm/.rbenv/plugins/rbenv-each/bin
 - /Users/ttm/.rbenv/shims
 - /Users/ttm/.rbenv/bin
```

Similarly, my `which pry` returns:

```
/Users/ttm/.rbenv/shims/pry
```

Using rbenv's [`env` plugin](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/wiki/Plugins) shows:

```
RBENV_VERSION=2.2.3
RBENV_GEMSET_ALREADY=yes
RBENV_ROOT=/Users/ttm/.rbenv
RBENV_HOOK_PATH=:/Users/ttm/.rbenv/rbenv.d:/usr/local/etc/rbenv.d:/etc/rbenv.d:/usr/lib/rbenv/hooks:/Users/ttm/.rbenv/plugins/rbenv-default-gems/etc/rbenv.d:/Users/ttm/.rbenv/plugins/rbenv-gemset/etc/rbenv.d:/Users/ttm/.rbenv/plugins/rbenv-readline/etc/rbenv.d:/Users/ttm/.rbenv/plugins/rbenv-vars/etc/rbenv.d
PATH=/Users/ttm/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin:/Users/ttm/.rbenv/libexec:/Users/ttm/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:/Users/ttm/.rbenv/plugins/rbenv-whatis/bin:/Users/ttm/.rbenv/plugins/rbenv-vars/bin:/Users/ttm/.rbenv/plugins/rbenv-use/bin:/Users/ttm/.rbenv/plugins/rbenv-update/bin:/Users/ttm/.rbenv/plugins/rbenv-update-rubies/bin:/Users/ttm/.rbenv/plugins/rbenv-gemset/bin:/Users/ttm/.rbenv/plugins/rbenv-env/bin:/Users/ttm/.rbenv/plugins/rbenv-each/bin:/Users/ttm/.rbenv/shims:/Users/ttm/.rbenv/bin:/Users/ttm/.pyenv/shims:/Users/ttm/.pyenv/bin:/Users/ttm/perl5/perlbrew/bin:/Users/ttm/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.18.1/bin:/Users/ttm/bin:/usr/local/mysql-5.6.16-osx10.7-x86_64/bin:/Users/ttm/libsmi/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
RBENV_SHELL=bash
RBENV_DIR=/Users/ttm
RUBYLIB=/Users/ttm/.rbenv/rbenv.d/exec/gem-rehash:
```

I'd do these steps:

1. Modify ~/.bashrc, and the others, removing any lines referring to rbenv and/or RVM. RVM uses all three init files, plus .zshrc, whereas rbenv only seems to touch ~/.bash_profile.
2. Close the terminal session. Reopen it.
3. Confirm the PATH is free from all references to RVM and rbenv.
4. Reinstall rbenv following the [Installation](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#installation) instructions. It won't override the current installation, but instead will reinstall its changes to ~/.bash_profile.
5. Close the terminal session again and reopen it.

rbenv should now be initialized correctly.

Comment: @TinMan you are the man.  Your suggestions worked like a charm.  I am now free of RVM. Something to note is I also reinstalled rbenv from github instead of from Arch Linux's AUR.  Lesson learned -- always better to install directly from the maintainers if you can.  Thanks again.

Comment: The maintainers know much more about how something works than the random blogger on the Internet. Too often we see outdated or out of context directions used to install these things, resulting in a bad installation. I'm glad it's working for you. Check out the various plugins for rbenv mentioned on the github page. I've found several to be quite useful.